How do I prevent Google Maps from loading as tiles?
I am using the @react-google-maps/api library to embed Google Maps into a React component. However, I've encountered an issue where the map tiles are not only visible but also display unusual diamond or star-shaped artifacts at each corner of the tiles.
What I have tried:

Ensuring the map loads asynchronously to prevent performance issues.
Checking for any errors in the console that might indicate a problem
with how the map is rendered
Adjusting the map's zoom and center
properties to see if the issue continues at different levels of
detail.

import { GoogleMap, LoadScript } from '@react-google-maps/api';

const containerStyle = {
  width: '400px',
  height: '400px'
};

const center = {
  lat: -3.745,
  lng: -38.523
};

function MyMapComponent() {
  return (
    <LoadScript
      googleMapsApiKey="YOUR_API_KEY"
    >
      <GoogleMap
        mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
        center={center}
        zoom={10}
      >
        {/* Map components here */}
      </GoogleMap>
    </LoadScript>
  );
}

export default MyMapComponent;


Does anyone know what might be causing these diamond/star-shaped artifacts at the tile corners? Any suggestions on how to fix or debug this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Check your CSS. You have border-radius applied on all images.

As @MrUpsidedown pointed out, I was applying a border-radius to all my images in my CSS. I removed it and that fixed the issue.
